# Confused about this line of code that is meant to act as an ingestion of a Class into a void pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, void

I've been learning how to send data to a program called FogLAMP https://github.com/foglamp/ and the data I want to send is asynchronous. My question is not about the foglamp code base itself, rather the below line of code.

I understand generally what the code is doing. But I do not know the exact mechanics in memory or the syntax for that matter.

I will do my best to describe what I believe is going on, but I am not entirely sure.

This is a code ingestion, so because the program is running two asynchronous threads, (the data collection and sending process (pid (1)) and the actual code set up as a daemon process (pid (2))) it is designed to allocate a void pointer (void * m_data) that will eventually be filled with a Reading object that should be sent to the cloud via process (1). This reading is produced, however, in process (2). So what I believe is going on is process (2) is producing a Reading object in memory so that process (1) can access that data.

I am lost when it comes to this line of code, though (I've included relevant code below to follow the execution path).

```cpp
void    (*m_ingest)(void *, Reading);
```

I haven't seen this syntax anywhere and I can't seem to describe this to google, so I'm not entirely sure what this means in C++.

I apologize I'm not able to provide much more information. I wasn't sure how to describe it, kind of like a cast to a type m_ingest (which is not a global variable or typedef).

I am looking through this code because I would like to implement the same thing into my own foglamp plugin using Robotic Operating Systems (ROS) as a multi threaded asynchronous data transfer to foglamp.

This is the code In question

```cpp
void    (*m_ingest)(void *, Reading);
void    *m_data;
```

These two variables appear in the below functions (not entirely sure what (*cb)(void *, Reading) means either.

```cpp
void OPCUA::registerIngest(void *data, void (*cb)(void *, Reading))
{
    m_ingest = cb;
    m_data = data;
}

/**
 * Called when a data changed event is received. This calls back to the south service
 * and adds the points to the readings queue to send.
 *
 * @param points    The points in the reading we must create
 */
void OPCUA::ingest(vector<Datapoint *>  points)
{
string asset = m_asset + points[0]->getName();

    (*m_ingest)(m_data, Reading(asset, points));
}
```

The comment is very helpful, stating that ingest puts the array of Datapoint pointers into a queue to be sent to foglamp. It makes sense, what this s doing, but I would like a more robust explanation as to what is actually going on in memory.

The source code In question is found in the repository
https://github.com/foglamp/foglamp-south-opcua

Here is the source code
https://github.com/foglamp/foglamp-south-opcua/blob/develop/opcua.cpp

Here is the header file
https://github.com/foglamp/foglamp-south-opcua/blob/develop/include/opcua.h

Comment: The term you're looking for is "pointer to function".

Comment: Which pointer are you referring to? m_ingest is not a function either. Nor cb. This would make perfect sense as it is pretty much just a callback, but I don't see a function pointer anywhere.

Comment: `m_ingest` is a function pointer.  It points to a function taking two parameters (`void *` and `int`) and returns nothing (`void`).  The `(*m_ingest)(m_data, Reading(asset, points))` line calls the pointed to function.

Comment: Ah great. you pointed me in the right direction. Just read over https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html. I'll read more about function pointers to get more comfortable but *cb is just a function pointer passed to register_injest then correct?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty basic c++ here. Thanks to @1201ProgramAlarm. It's just a function pointer. I read a quick tutorial here https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html. But I now see that (*cb) is a function pointer passed through register_ingest to assign m_ingest to the same function as (*cb). Thus when foglamp needs data it accesses it through m_ingest. This function helps a lot

```cpp
void plugin_register_ingest(PLUGIN_HANDLE *handle, INGEST_CB cb, void *data)
{
OPCUA *opcua = (OPCUA *)handle;

    if (!handle)
        throw new exception();
    opcua->registerIngest(data, cb);
}
```

So INGEST_CB is a global callback function defined in some foglamp header file that then is assigned to the same address as m_ingest.

Humbling to learn something new in C++. I have never seen function pointers passed this way, only function addresses (i.e. through std::bind(&func, param)).